# Calculate min() and max() of each matrix column

Tags: r, matrix, range, min

I'm using the following matrix:

`dput(data)` =

```
structure(c(269.643848985434, 284.856715574861, 278.687093704939, 
242.00628682971, 258.754844814539, 257.241126745939, 250.868861973286, 
267.881099879742, 266.277047023177, 264.643696397543, 283.306375294924, 
278.137760534883, 251.230201125145, 264.389782398939, 260.087893307209, 
263.933225497603, 284.947050362825, 279.185155779123, 262.722251042724, 
284.903103709221, 279.329203143716, 256.589251384139, 274.861293360591, 
270.730307921767, 233.265785723925, 249.657887518406, 247.94396802783, 
264.665669724345, 284.124271348119, 278.701742589474, 0, 0, 0
), dim = c(3L, 11L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "gt")))
```

and, for each column, I'd like to find the range of values (`min` and `max`?) and save them (f.e. in a list).

What would be an easy way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`range()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/range):

> `range` returns a vector containing the minimum and maximum of all the given arguments.

Use `apply()` with `MARGIN = 2` to iterate over each column, applying the `range()` function. Then set appropriate row names, e.g. `c("min", "max")`. As you want a list, use [`asplit()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/asplit) to split the columns of the resulting matrix into a list of vectors.

Assuming your matrix is called `m`:

```r
apply(m, MARGIN = 2, range)  |>
    `rownames<-`(c("min", "max"))  |>
    asplit(MARGIN = 2)

# [[1]]
#      min      max 
# 269.6438 284.8567 

# [[2]]
#      min      max 
# 242.0063 258.7548 

# [[3]]
#      min      max 
# 250.8689 267.8811 

# [[4]]
#      min      max 
# 264.6437 283.3064 

# [[5]]
#      min      max 
# 251.2302 264.3898 

# [[6]]
#      min      max 
# 263.9332 284.9471 

# [[7]]
#      min      max 
# 262.7223 284.9031 

# [[8]]
#      min      max 
# 256.5893 274.8613 

# [[9]]
#      min      max 
# 233.2658 249.6579 

# [[10]]
#      min      max 
# 264.6657 284.1243 

# $gt
# min max 
#   0   0
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me draw your attention to the **matrixStats** package. It's nut just syntactic sugar, it's also implemented in C++ and, thus, very fast.

```
matrixStats::colRanges(m)
#        [,1]     [,2]
#    269.6438 284.8567
#    242.0063 258.7548
#    250.8689 267.8811
#    264.6437 283.3064
#    251.2302 264.3898
#    263.9332 284.9471
#    262.7223 284.9031
#    256.5893 274.8613
#    233.2658 249.6579
#    264.6657 284.1243
# gt   0.0000   0.0000
```

Comment: Superb `colRanges`, didn't know it before, +1!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tapply` + `col` + `range` like below

```
> tapply(data, col(data), range)
$`1`
[1] 269.6438 284.8567

$`2`
[1] 242.0063 258.7548

$`3`
[1] 250.8689 267.8811

$`4`
[1] 264.6437 283.3064

$`5`
[1] 251.2302 264.3898

$`6`
[1] 263.9332 284.9471

$`7`
[1] 262.7223 284.9031

$`8`
[1] 256.5893 274.8613

$`9`
[1] 233.2658 249.6579

$`10`
[1] 264.6657 284.1243

$`11`
[1] 0 0
```